# get specific table into excel using VBA

Tags: vba, innerhtml

I am looking for a way to get a table into excel using VBA. Using a web query is not suitable for specific reasons.

So far i have got this

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Navigate "http://bmreports.com/servlet/com.logica.neta.bwp_PanBMUTop"
ie.Visible = True
While ie.Busy
DoEvents
Wend
ie.document.getelementbyid("param5").Value = "2014-04-12"
ie.document.getelementbyid("param6").Value = "8"
ie.document.getelementbyid("go_button").Click
```

The web page that opens has a table within it called Maximum Export Limit - half way down the page and on the left hand side.

I found the part of the html code that is responsible for the table and manged to copy the inner html to the web page manually (just copy and pasting) however how do i do this via VBA>

@Ron
So far i have this in all

```
Sub DataStuff()
Dim ie As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Navigate "http://bmreports.com/servlet/com.logica.neta.bwp_PanBMUTop"
ie.Visible = True
While ie.Busy
DoEvents
Wend
ie.Document.getelementbyid("param5").Value = "2014-04-12"
ie.Document.getelementbyid("param6").Value = "8"
ie.Document.getelementbyid("go_button").Click

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
    On Error Resume Next    ' sometimes more web pages are counted than are open
    my_url = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Location
    my_title = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Title

    If my_url Like "http://bmreports.com/servlet/com.logica.neta.bwp_PanBMDataServlet" Then
        Set ie = objShell.Windows(x)
```

table_html = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(2).innerhtml

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell = table_html
        Exit For
    Else
    End If









Next





End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on the "go_button" a new web page is opened, but your macro remains focused on the original web page.  Insert the following after your "click" line.  This code will find the new web page and place focus on it

```
Sub DataStuff()
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        ie.Navigate "http://bmreports.com/servlet/com.logica.neta.bwp_PanBMUTop"
        ie.Visible = True

    Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    ie.Document.getelementbyid("param5").Value = "2014-04-12"
    ie.Document.getelementbyid("param6").Value = "8"
    ie.Document.getelementbyid("go_button").Click

    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
    For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
        On Error Resume Next    ' sometimes more web pages are counted than are open
        my_url = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Location
        my_title = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Title

        If my_url Like "http://bmreports.com/servlet/com.logica.neta.bwp_PanBMDataServlet" Then
            Set ie = objShell.Windows(x)
            Exit For
        Else
        End If
    Next

    table_html = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(2).innerhtml
    html_lines = Split(table_html, Chr(10), -1, vbTextCompare)

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("A1").Select

    For x = 0 To UBound(html_lines)
        ActiveCell = html_lines(x)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, how do i get the data in the cell a1 of sheet1?

Comment: I edited my answer to include putting the html in cell A1 of sheet1

Comment: Hi Ron will do although the code doesnt seem to bring back the data not sure whats wrong. i have got the full code so far in my initial post

Comment: i see the data put into 1 cell a list of everything with codes</t> and all the rest of it, i thought i would get the table only? is this not the case?

Comment: @Ingram You did not copy my code correctly.  For example, the "Exit For" is in the wrong place in your code.  In any case, I have re-edited my code; I have only changed what's at the bottom.  This code will extract the html (BTw, if you change ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(2).innerhtml to ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(2).innertext you will get the table text instead of the table html - which do you want?) from the "Maximum Export Limit" table only.  The code I've added at the end will split the html into individual lines and put each line in a separate cell starting

Comment: with "A1" on sheet1.  This code works for me, let me know if you have a problem.

Comment: you are definetly making progress, wow, i now have the data in the spreadsheet as you described. I used .innertext rather than the html. However im not sure if this to much to ask, as you have helped me on my way a lot. It would be great if the formats were similar, or the same, to the table on the website as a lot of the words are joint together making it difficult to do anything with.

Comment: for example if i copy and paste the 2nd line i would get all the items in each cell.

Comment: 8       2014-04-12 02:30      -213.000    2014-04-12 03:00    -213.000

Comment: even if it had commas between each item then i could apply text to columns

Comment: VBA can do the formatting.  There are a lot of lines of data, to many for me to try.  You could do it yourself or post another question.

Comment: okay :( its only the lines with the period, date items and fomr level that causes the problem

Comment: i noticed on the page that contains the data there is a link on the top left that called current data in csv, is it possible to get that in the worskeet instead? That would be in the right format